# Set image from iTunes Extras's gallery as desktop picture

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-store, wallpaper

I just bought Mad Max: Fury Road from iTunes and wanted to set my desktop picture as one of the stills from the iTunes Extras's gallery.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to take a screenshot of the image. This is accomplished by pressing Cmd-Shift-4 and selecting the outline of the rectangle that you want to capture with the mouse.

Comment: it's a way but definitely not what I want. Maybe tomorrow I will spend sometime looking for it on my iTunes foder